# Python: spawn or thread for long running background process?

Tags: python, background-process, spawn

I am planning to make a long running background process with Python but I am still unsure whether to use `os.spawnle` or thread. I've only read about it therefore I have not much experience with either spawn or thread. Is there any rule of thumb when to use which?

Thanks heaps

Comment: How long will this be running? Maybe make it a daemon?

Comment: Yes daemon might be a good option. But if I want to fork the process, would it be possible with daemon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure that you take the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) into account. If the long running process is CPU intensive, you should probably make it an independent process. If on the other hand, it's going to spend a lot of time blocking, then the GIL isn't really that big of a deal and you should be fine to make it a thread.

Also, if you don't need something in particular that `os.spawnle` provides, consider using the  [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) package from the standard library. It provides an interface similar to that of the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) package and is altogether easier to use than mucking around with manually spawning and tracking processes.

Comment: Never thought of `multiprocessing` module. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious difference is that `os.spawnle` is used to start another process running a *different* program, whereas a thread would be executing code that's part of the *same* program.  In fact, if your background process is some other program that already exists, then `os.spawnle` (or some other means of creating a separate process) is your only option; two threads in a program have to be running the same program.

If you wondering whether you should structure your own code to be run as separate processes or as separate threads, then take a look at some of the [process v. thread questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921/process-vs-threads) to decide which better fits what you're trying to do.  In particular, consider what resources the processes/threads will need to share, what they will communicate with each other, and how robust each needs to be -- a thread that crashes will bring the rest of the process down with it, for example.